# Sound Waves and air molecules movement

Tags: acoustics

All the resources which I have read till now always represented the air mass to be a stationary set of particles undergoing infinitely small displacement from their equilibrium (mean) position when sound travels through them but,I have also read that air particles (even if no wind is blowing) are in continuous movement. Which actually contradicts my imagination.Basically my question is that if the air particles are not at rest like the sting particles then how can one consider them to show the same kind of behavior as string particles.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295746/25301 (unanswered, but the comments might be fruitful)

Answer (score 3):

Air molecules do indeed jiggle around randomly all the time.  That is a microscopic phenomenon.  A sound wave traveling through air is more or less a macroscopic thing--in order to describe it in the terms you do a wave on a string (which, by the way, is a transverse wave, unlike sound waves in air), you have to look on a large enough scale that those random molecular motions blur together, and things appear smooth and predictable.  Then you can talk about pressure, density, and fluid velocity, and the thermal motions don't come into it.

You can understand these concepts--pressure, density, and fluid velocity--from a microscopic viewpoint.  That's a statistical endeavor--if you have more air molecules in one area than a nearby one, for instance, probability says that the random thermal motion of the molecules will move more of the molecules from the dense area to the sparse area than from the sparse area to the dense one.  This makes it clear that, far from ruling out sound propagation, the random thermal motions of air molecules are the very thing that allow it.  Sound cannot propagate faster than those thermal motions, because it is an average of those motions that carries the information from place to place.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are wondering why sound can travel through air when air particles are constantly moving.

Have you ever seen waves in traffic? The cars are all moving, but sometimes the flow of cars gets restricted and everyone slows down, then everyone starts moving - this is a pressure wave, like sound.  I give this example because it is more similar to sound waves in air than waves on a string.

Some videos of traffic waves are 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh6PNQbKBYo)
and
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZC9h8jgSj4)

Another point is that sound travels better through liquids and solids than air - probably because the liquid and solid particles move much less than the air particles although they are not completely stationary. (So your intuition that sound waves travelling through moving air particles seems improbable is maybe reflected in the way that sound travels better through liquids and solids where the particles don't move so much.)